# Change another user's umask on macosx

Tags: osx, umask

How can I change another user's umask on Mac OS X? [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36220/8474) only has answers that work on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a mac user here but I noted it a while back, while helping a family friend.

you can set the umask by putting a line like this:

```
umask 022
```

into one of these:

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login   (if .bash_profile does not exist)
~/.profile      (if .bash_login does not exist)
```

also, if you have it,  `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` is another place you can put the line in